# onclick event - call a button using something other than id

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, autoresize

I am trying to rerun a block of javascript when the user clicks on a button. The site was created in a CMS so I do not have access to the button to give it an id. However, in firebug I noticed it has these values ->

```
<input type="submit" value="Continue">
```

Is there anyway I can call to this by using the value of 'Continue'?

FYI: the button is coded with php and I want to rerun the following

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function resizePole(){
    var ht=($('#LayoutColumn2').height() > $('#LayoutColumn3').height()) ?
    $('#LayoutColumn2').height() : $('#LayoutColumn3').height(); $('#lightPole').height(ht); }); </script>
```

and I am attempting to call this using:

```
onclick="return resizePole();"
```

Oh and I know next to nothing about javascript :)

Link to page working on - you may have to create a customer account. Enter some jibberish and I can delete it later

[link to site](https://store-e262c.mybigcommerce.com/checkout.php?tk=3ccf1a0f50d50f8e0c62e4ee32350001)

What the problem is: Ok let me explain what should be happening. I have created a div called 'lightpole' this div contains a background image of a lightpole that is coded with javascript to match the height of the 'content' div when the page loads. On the checkout_express page the creators of the CMS system have created expanding and collapsible divs that guide the user through the checkout process. On the third step 'Shipping Method' the user clicks on the 'Continue' button which expands the 'Order Confirmation Step'. This div causes the 'content' div to be longer than on initial loading but the lightpole was only sized to match the inital height of the content, not the added height of the Order Confirmation Step so it causes the lightpole to be shorter than it actually needs to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work.

```
$('[type="submit"][value="Continue"]').click(function () {
{
    return resizePole();
});
```

**EDIT**

As pointed out in the comments, there is a more concise way to do this. I typically use the method above out of habit (makes it easier to add future logic to the click event).

```
$('[type="submit"][value="Continue"]').click(resizePole);
```

**EDIT 2**

To answer the question in the comments - yes, you can filter by the div ID as well. This will attach to the click event of all submit buttons inside a div with an id of DivIdHere and a value of Continue.

```
$('#DivIdHere [type="submit"][value="Continue"]').click(resizePole);
```

**EDIT 3**

This is a bit dirty, but after looking at your updated requirments, this should do the trick. Basically, it adds the click event to the last submit button on the page that has a value of continue (which appears to be the shipping section based on the link you provided).

```
$('[type="submit"][value="Continue"]:last').click(resizePole);
```

Comment: He has JQuery syntax in his question ;)

Comment: What the... why are you returning the value of a function inside an anonymous function? `function(){return a();}` == `a`

Comment: @James Hill - I think there there is more than one instance of value Continue

Comment: @bjstone15, As long as there isn't more than one submit button with the value of continue, you're fine. This only finds submit buttons with a value of continue.

Comment: @Hello71 - what are you talking about? (I'm a huge newb to jquery)

Comment: @James Hill - did some double checking and there is more than one instance. Is it possible to narrow is down by targeting the div it's in? kind of like in css

Comment: @bjstrong15, How many submit buttons do you have that have a value of `Continue`?

Comment: @bjstone, just reference jquery library in your code and the code above should run. If u have more than one button with continue you can use eq(index) to specify which button click you want to capture. Also since it is submit button, you need to use preventDefault() to stop submission

Comment: @hungryMind, `preventDefault()` is not required if the method returns false.

Comment: @James Hill - It looks like 3

Comment: @bjstone15 - take a look at the code above. You should have everything you need to make this work (including the code to filter by ID).

Comment: @hungryMind - I edited the code referenced here to include the library which I already had in the code. I have no idea was eq(index) means or how to use it. To google!

Comment: @bjstone15, forget the eq stuff. Try out the code above for pete's sake :)!

Comment: All - here is the link to the page I am working on > https://store-e262c.mybigcommerce.com/checkout.php?tk=3ccf1a0f50d50f8e0c62e4ee32350001 If it asks you to create an account go to New Customer and enter some jibberish as I am able to edit customers.

Comment: @bjstone15, have you tried the code above? If so, what exactly didn't work about it? I think you're making this more complicated than it really is.

Comment: @James - I have explained what I am trying to do up top underneath the rest of the code. and Yes I am probably making this way more complicated than necessary :P

Comment: @bjstone15, I took a look at your link. See edit 3. As you can see, there is a ton of flexibility using the jQuery selectors. If the 3rd edit doesn't work for you, I'm afraid I can't help anymore - we're going past the scope of the original questions (given the updated requirements).

Comment: Sorry, it didn't. The Firebug error console is saying that resize pole is not defined. I may move this over to another question page are youre correct, this is beyond the question.